# grouping duplicates and combining the string columns via Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

let's say I have the following pandas dataframe called `example`:

```
city    state  school_lvl    schl_name     elem_name   middle_name   highschoo_name
Orlando  fl        1         Union Park    Union Park
Orlando  fl        2         Legacy                      Legacy
Orlando   fl       3         Colonial                                  Colonial
```

where columns like `elem_name` were generated using if conditions on `school_lvl` and `schl_name`

what I would like instead is

```
city    state  elem_name   middle_name   highschoo_name
Orlando  fl   Union Park    Legacy        Colonial
```

How would I go about doing this? It's not really a groupie since there is no aggregate function? I'd greatly appreciate any help

Answer (score 1):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with lambda function for forward and back filling and then [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) by first 2 and last 3 columns:

```
c = example.columns[:2].tolist() + example.columns[-3:].tolist()
print (c)
['city', 'state', 'elem_name', 'middle_name', 'highschoo_name']

df = example.groupby(['city', 'state']).apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill()).drop_duplicates(c)
print (df)
      city state  school_lvl   schl_name   elem_name middle_name  \
0  Orlando    fl           1  Union Park  Union Park      Legacy   

  highschoo_name  
0       Colonial
```

If want remove columns simplier is first [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) and then remove duplicates by all columns:

```
example = example.drop(['school_lvl','schl_name'], axis=1)
df = example.groupby(['city', 'state']).apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill()).drop_duplicates()
print (df)
      city state   elem_name middle_name highschoo_name
0  Orlando    fl  Union Park      Legacy       Colonial
```

Comment: @ScottBoston - Yes, I add link. Good idea.

Comment: first thank you for your response. Unfortunately the first code deleted all rows besides the first and the second code keep the dataframe the same. I have updated the question with more information

Comment: unfortunately I got the following error `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'columns'`